# Generating entity in Jhipster Module

Tags: jhipster, yeoman-generator

Im writing a Jhipster generator module and I need to scaffold a new entity. Just like running jhipster:entity but inside the generator javascript

How should I do this? I see in the base generator methods "addEntityToCache(...)", "addEntityToMenu(...)". But I don't see: "addEntity(definition)" where definition is the configuration json that it's stored in .jhipster

It's this feature possible? can I extend the entity sub-generator to reuse the code?

Answer (score 0):

Create entity.json file inside project/.jhipster

{
    "fluentMethods": true,

```
"relationships": [],
"fields": [
    {
        "fieldName": "field_name_in_pojo_class",
        "fieldType": "data_type_of_that_field"
    }
],
"changelogDate": "20180523121144",
"dto": "no",
"service": "serviceClass",
"entityTableName": "entity_name_here",
"jpaMetamodelFiltering": false,
"pagination": "pagination",
"microserviceName": "project_name_here",
"searchEngine": false
```

}

Comment: but then, how I trigger the "jhipster:entity myentity" from my module? I want to add code in the resource controller after the code generation.